# Different iframe for different devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, iframe

I have a problem with Iframe in Wordpress.
I want to put HTML5 product (calculator) into Wordpress post and today I have something like this:

In post:

```
<iframe class="iframe" src="http://sitename.../index.html" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

And in CSS:

```
.iframe { width: 300px; height: 225px; }
@media (min-width:400px) { .iframe { width: 350px; height: 263px; } }
@media (min-width:700px) { .iframe { width: 600px; height: 451px; } }
```

And here is the problem:
When I open this HTML (besides Wordpress) in all devices it looks very nice and it is fully responsive.

When I open this HTML in Wordpress by Iframe then HTML product fill good all Iframe, but fonts and images looks like "pixelate". I guess that HTML is opening as 1024x768 width (it is starting width/height) and later it is scaling for Iframe.

And here is **my question - how to make this Iframe correct to have a nice looking fonts/images in all devices?**

Comment: apart from the width and height also set font-size

Comment: But it isn't problem only with text - for example images also are shown as "pixelate". I need better solve for this problem ;)

Comment: Do you use any of WP plugins for iFrames? Have you installed any?

Comment: No, I didn't have any kind of plugins for Iframe :) I wanted to make it by myself in css.

Comment: It is probably the other way around. Going from big to small doesn't usually result in pixelated images, the other way around it does. Your initial size for `iframe` is 300x225. Then for the other media you scale it up to 350x263 and so on. But it is hard to say without seeing the full code. Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I changed initial size into 1024x768 and still the same effect ;) It will be difficult to create jsfiddle, sorry :( I guess that problem is in order of initializing code - it looks like HTML (with JS) is loaded earlier and later it fits into Iframe.

Comment: That is too bad, can't do much without code, but maybe someone else can.